# T-SQL UPDATE query not giving expected results

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an UPDATE query in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 that is not giving me the expected results.  I believe it is because I had to add the IJDATE field to the SELECT and GROUP BY and therefore it is not summing correctly.  I am trying to update the current month/year for each vendor.  Is there a better way to write this UPDATE query?

```
UPDATE S
SET S.PurchaseDlr = I.PurchaseDlr
FROM (SELECT 
          IJVEND,
          IJDATE,
          SUM(IJQTY * IJCOST) AS PurchaseDlr
      FROM
          dbo.S2K_IJ
      WHERE
          IJTYPE IN ('I','ID')
      GROUP BY
          IJVEND,
          IJDATE) I
INNER JOIN PurchaseDollars S on I.IJVEND = S.Vendor AND S.MonthNum = MONTH(I.IJDATE) AND S.Year = YEAR(I.IJDATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by date, but it looks like you want to group by month and year:

```
UPDATE S
SET S.PurchaseDlr = I.PurchaseDlr
FROM (SELECT 
          IJVEND,
          MONTH(IJDATE) AS Month,
          YEAR(IJDATE) AS Year,
          SUM(IJQTY * IJCOST) AS PurchaseDlr
      FROM
          dbo.S2K_IJ
      WHERE
          IJTYPE IN ('I','ID')
      GROUP BY
          IJVEND,
          MONTH(IJDATE),
          YEAR(IJDATE)) I
INNER JOIN PurchaseDollars S 
    ON I.IJVEND = S.Vendor 
        AND S.MonthNum = I.Month
        AND S.Year = I.Year
```